# Flutter App won't compile, CocoaPods fails Pod Install

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

I have an Image Picker dependency in my app, it's always worked fine as far as I'm aware and all of a sudden I can't compile my app for iOS. It's throwing me an error related to CocoaPods, I'm really not sure what to do about it. Error is below, do you have any idea what I could do to resolve that situation? Thanks in advance !

```
### Stack


   CocoaPods : 1.11.3
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [arm64-darwin21]
    RubyGems : 3.4.2
        Host : macOS 12.6.1 (21G217)
       Xcode : 14.0.1 (14A400)
         Git : git version 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136)
Ruby lib dir : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.0/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/


### Plugins


cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0


### Podfile

ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    # Workaround https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111475.
    target_is_resource_bundle = target.respond_to?(:product_type) && target.product_type == 'com.apple.product-type.bundle'
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
      if target_is_resource_bundle
        build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
        build_configuration.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY'] = '-'
        build_configuration.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = '-'
      end
    end

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # You can remove unused permissions here
      # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
#        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
#        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
#        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
#         'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
#        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
#        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
#        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
#         'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
#        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
#        'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
#        'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
#        'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1',
      ]

    end
  end
end


### Error


NoMethodError - undefined method `=~' for [["PICKER_MEDIA=1"], ["PICKER_AUDIO=1"], ["PICKER_DOCUMENT=1"]]:Array
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `block (2 levels) in merged_xcconfigs'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `all?'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:446:in `block in merged_xcconfigs'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in `each_with_object'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:444:in `merged_xcconfigs'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:1057:in `block in <class:PodTargetSettings>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/target/build_settings.rb:120:in `block in define_build_settings_method'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:177:in `block in remove_pod_target_xcconfig_overrides_from_target'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:174:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:174:in `remove_pod_target_xcconfig_overrides_from_target'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:157:in `block in add_target'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:156:in `add_target'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:47:in `block in install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pod_target_installer.rb:40:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:115:in `block in install_pod_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `map'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:112:in `install_pod_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:32:in `block in install_all_pod_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:31:in `install_all_pod_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/single_pods_project_generator.rb:19:in `generate!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:314:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:301:in `generate_pods_project'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:167:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do you have multiple Pods inside your Xcode? See this: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/310370/35758021-a7cbec1e-0826-11e8-9d4e-3ba9551d87e8.png

Comment: @targiasld I did have that, removed it and it's still throwing me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Running `brew reinstall cocoapods` fixed the issue.